# Howto set up only BG color of window, not all child widgets

Tags: gtk, application-development

I need change only background colour of window, and keep widgets in system colours.

The space between boxes should keep different colour

http://ubuntuone.com/756mWfF2hTYwgiGCOccmEz

Something like this

http://ubuntuone.com/3jCDQHtSt6KJfbYQ6YMH7F

I don't know if clutter is here better way to make it look this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not specified the programming language, so I assume Python for simplicity reasons.

In gtk, most components can connect to an expose event which can then be used to draw manually into the widget ([cairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) is used for this, all those widgets have a cairo context attached to them)

Here is a simple example of a window with a custom colored Vbox and two buttons, the space between the bottons (here set to 20 pixels) and the small border around the buttons shows the background color of the VBox.

```
import gtk


class MyColoredBox(gtk.VBox):
    def __init__(self, homogeneous=False, spacing=0):
        super(MyColoredBox, self).__init__(homogeneous, spacing)
        self.connect("expose-event", self.expose)

    def expose(self, widget, event):
        cr = widget.window.cairo_create()
        cr.set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 0.5)
        cr.rectangle(event.area.x, event.area.y,
                     event.area.width, event.area.height)
        cr.fill()


class PyApp(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        vbox = MyColoredBox(False, 20)
        b1 = gtk.Button("Hello")
        b2 = gtk.Button("World")
        vbox.add(b1)
        vbox.add(b2)
        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PyApp()
    gtk.main()
```

The resulting programm looks something like this:
[image]